# PyParsing Or executes as a matchFirst Or

Tags: python-2.7, pyparsing

I built 2 grammars which partly overlap each other. I would like the grammar matching best to the text to be selected. Therefore I wrote a third grammar with an Or statement. I searched on the internet and understand that an ^ selects the grammar returning the longest text, instead of only selecting the first grammar in the Or statement.

When I run the code it always selects the first grammar, instead of matching the best one. This is also the case when I turn the two grammars around in the ^ statement. Does someone has a clue why this is happening?

I am using Python 2.7.13 and PyParsing 2.1.4.

(The Or statement can be found in grammar type1 on the third line)

```
advice1 = (ZeroOrMore(~Literal('Home') + WORD) + Literal('Home')
    + OneOrMore(~Literal('Street') + WORD)('Home').setParseAction(' '.join, standardizeStrings)
    + Literal('Street') + UPPERCASEWORDS('Facility').setParseAction(''.join, standardizeStrings)
    + SkipTo("-----") + restOfLine + EOL #1
    + OneOrMore(~AMOUNT + WORD).setParseAction(' '.join) + AMOUNT + AMOUNT('CPB').setParseAction(convertAmountString) + DATE
    + SkipTo("-----") + restOfLine + EOL #2
    + OneOrMore(~AMOUNT + WORD).setParseAction(' '.join) + AMOUNT + AMOUNT('TOI').setParseAction(convertAmountString) + Optional(DATE)
    + SkipTo("_____") + restOfLine + EOL #3
    + DATE + DATE + Word(nums) + CURRENCY + AMOUNT + RATE + AMOUNT
    + SkipTo("-----") + restOfLine + EOL #4
    + OneOrMore(~AMOUNT + WORD).setParseAction(' '.join) + AMOUNT + AMOUNT('PB').setParseAction(convertAmountString) + DATE('New_Date').setParseAction(convertDateString)
)

advice2 = (ZeroOrMore(~Literal('Home') + WORD) + Literal('Home')
    + OneOrMore(~Literal('Street') + WORD)('Home').setParseAction(' '.join, standardizeStrings)
    + Literal('Street') + UPPERCASEWORDS('Facility').setParseAction(''.join, standardizeStrings)
    + SkipTo("-----") + restOfLine + EOL #1
    + OneOrMore(~AMOUNT + WORD).setParseAction(' '.join) + AMOUNT + AMOUNT('CPB').setParseAction(convertAmountString) + DATE
    + SkipTo("-----") + restOfLine + EOL #2
    + (OneOrMore(~AMOUNT + WORD).setParseAction(' '.join) ^ AMOUNT) + AMOUNT + AMOUNT('TIA').setParseAction(convertAmountString) + Optional(DATE)
    + SkipTo("-----") + restOfLine + EOL #3
    + OneOrMore(~AMOUNT + WORD).setParseAction(' '.join) + AMOUNT + AMOUNT('TOI').setParseAction(convertAmountString) + Optional(DATE)
    + SkipTo("_____") + restOfLine + EOL #4
    + DATE + DATE + Word(nums) + CURRENCY + AMOUNT + RATE + AMOUNT
    + SkipTo("-----") + restOfLine + EOL #5
    + OneOrMore(~AMOUNT + WORD).setParseAction(' '.join) + AMOUNT + AMOUNT('PB').setParseAction(convertAmountString) + DATE('New_Date').setParseAction(convertDateString)
)

type1 = (OneOrMore(~Literal('Effective') + WORD)
    + Literal('Effective') + SEP + DATE('Effective_Date').setParseAction(convertDateString)
    + OneOrMore(Group(advice1 ^ advice2))('Facility') # OR statement
    + Optional(OneOrMore(~Literal("rate is") + WORD) + Literal("rate is") + RATE('Rate').setParseAction(convertRateString))
    + OneOrMore(~DATE + WORD) + DATE('Date').setParseAction(convertDateString)
    + Optional(notifications)
    + ZeroOrMore(~Literal('Home') + WORD)
)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make some more sense to refactor the grammars so that the common parts could be parsed only once? Also, I am not sure about greediness of `ZeroOrMore` and `OneOrMore` repetitions in `advice1` and `advice2`. It may well be that `^` alternative makes them accept strings of the same length which does not seem to be what you want. Worth checking too...